# SQL Delete based on max value

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have a table that has a composite key of 3 columns

```
st_id, sj_id, order
```

and want to delete a row based on a specific st_id and sj_id and by taking the max(order)

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you'll need to do this in two steps (this is from memory, so may not compile first time):

```
DELETE
FROM table
WHERE st_id = my_st_id
AND sj_id = my_sj_id 
AND order IN (
  SELECT MAX(order)
  FROM table
  WHERE st_id = my_st_id
  AND sj_id = my_sj_id)
```

What this does is perform the inner (SELECT) query first, returning the maximum order.  Those results then get passed to the outer query which does the delete.